# How to address denominations of cash?

Tags: apostrophe, numbers, money

"Please bring lots of $1.00s and $5.00s" or "Please bring lots of $1.00's and 5.00's"?

Comment: ...lots of one and five-dollar notes!

Comment: Georges...Abes...Benjamins, Benjamins, Benjamins...

Comment: Please address them all to me! :) I would go with the first over the latter, but might say, "1's and 5's" if we'd already established enough context to do so.

Comment: What do you mean by "lots"???

Comment: How about, "Please bring lots of one and five dollar bills."

Answer (score 3):

It's often recommended to write out small numbers in full, and in this case it makes sense and is clear.

> "Please bring lots of one dollar and five dollar bills".

If it's already clearly established that you are talking about dollar currency:

> "Please bring lots of ones and fives"

Comment: Use of a style guide is recommended. DJ's solution is consistent with *The Chicago Manual of Style*. Some more examples: 747s, 1970s, and Roaring Twenties